# Can't Read Firebase Data with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to create a simple Firebase application, and I have previously done so on Android. I am learning swift and was following the basic tutorials provided by Firebase.

I have successfully added Firebase through CocoaPods, however I am having trouble reading the result:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mLabel: UILabel!

var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://ios-weather-practice.firebaseio.com")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        if let baseResult = snapshot.value.objectForKey("ios-weather-practice") {
            self.mLabel.text = baseResult as? String
        }
    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


}
```

Error:

```
    2016-04-14 16:37:06.424 Firebase Sample[1833:1735025] -           [NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000747365744
2016-04-14 16:37:06.432 Firebase Sample[1833:1735025] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa000000747365744'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066f5f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108419deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066fe56d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010664beea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010664ba98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Firebase Sample                     0x0000000106367759 _TFFC15Firebase_Sample14ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_U_FGSQCSo13FDataSnapshot_T_ + 329
    6   Firebase Sample                     0x00000001063679f7 _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo13FDataSnapshot__dT__XFo_iGSQS___iT__ + 23
    7   Firebase Sample                     0x0000000106366d81 _TPA__TTRXFo_oGSQCSo13FDataSnapshot__dT__XFo_iGSQS___iT__ + 81
    8   Firebase Sample                     0x0000000106367a30 _TTRXFo_iGSQCSo13FDataSnapshot__iT__XFo_oGSQS___dT__ + 32
    9   Firebase Sample                     0x0000000106367a78 _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo13FDataSnapshot__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS___dT__ + 56
    10  Firebase                            0x00000001064316e1 __43-[FValueEventRegistration fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke53 + 78
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010980ae5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010982b49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001098132af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066562e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066178a9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106616e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ace9ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106f1230d UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Firebase Sample                     0x000000010636840d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010985f92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Firebase Database:

[image]

Comment: You are treating a string as a dictionary. Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: How do I determine which line? I am new to swift programming.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing by .Value will read in the entire contents of a node.

So if your structure is like this

```
myRootRef
   iso-weather-practice: "sunny"
```

Your event will be ok and it could be read like this

```
self.mLabel.text = baseResult as? String
```

However, that's not usually how a Firebase structure would appear. It would be more like this

```
myRootRef
   -JYa6s6gij900is
      date: "20160413"
      weather: "sunny"
   -JY9398iias98o4
      date: "20160414"
      weather: "blowing snow"
```

and in that case. .Value will read in that entire node, and the snapshot will contain multiple nodes (as key:value  pairs)

So here's how to handle it:

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children {
        if let w = child.value.objectForKey("weather") as? String {
          print(w)
        }
    }

})
```

output will be

```
sunny
blowing snow
```

Comment: Does the "?" denote that there is a possibility that the item is null? In other words, is this an example of optional binding?

Comment: @tccpg288 Yes! It's designed to protect your code in that if child contains nothing, the code will silently move on without crashing. If you haven't done so, search on Swift Optional and check out the tutorial that Apple posted. It's a good read.

Comment: I have multiple clusters(c1,c2,c3 etc) in my Firebase DB and lets say I want to first display all nodes/objects in that particular cluster. I do 
self.ref.child("c1").observe(.Value ... 
and I do get all of them. I have set another method to observe any change in any object of c1, for which I do 
self.ref.child("c1").observe(.childChanged, 
now the problem is whenever a change is detected, both of these methods are being called. I first get the changed node and then the entire cluster again. Any help here?

Comment: @YashTamakuwala We would be happy to help! Please create a new question outlining the issue and include your code and Firebase structure (as text please, no images) and we will take a look!

Comment: @Jay . are firebase callback's invoked by the client on the main thread or should I use `ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in DispatchQueue.main.async { // update the User Interface on the main thread } })` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if let baseResult = snapshot.value as? String {
    self.mLabel.text = baseResult
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove the .objectForKey portion of my code? It actually works, I appreciate the help. Not sure exactly what you did, however. I am no longer references the ios-weather-practice key

Comment: @tccpg288 from your data it looks that your ref variable points directly to a root node with is the object represented in firebase GUI under ios-weather-practice key, which is probably the name of your firebase app. Calling value on that object returns the value under that key.

Comment: This answer needs more explanation as it will not work properly if the node contains additional child values and will crash with a dictionary to string assignment error.

Comment: @Jay the code shouldn't be defensive. Since the data is structured this way the code works perfectly fine. I'm always agains defensive programming. And especially in a tutorial case, which is the case we have here.

Comment: Oh, I agree. However, the OP didn't post the structure, so I didn't want to assume what it was. Also, highlighting a more 'big picture' Firebase example (leveraging autoId's, proper structure, iterating over the snapshots etc). may help more in the long run. Your answer is very correct though for a single key:value pair situation and accounting for the optional is perfect.